# Excel: macro to update links in another macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master folder with all spreadsheets. 
Once I week I have to create new week folder and copy all master files there, so all reports can be updated daily for that week.
In one of the files I have 7 macros for each of the day. Evey macro is almost same apart of where it points to and what day data is retrieving. Each of the macros change pivot table to specific day e.g. Monday, Tuesday etc... then copy all data and paste into temp. Monday data into Monday temp etc. Then it saves and close that temp.
The file structure is:

```
C:\Reports\Weekly Report\Week XX\Monday Report.xls
```

XX is number of current week.

What I would like to do is have a macro that if in cell A5 is e.g. 42 will change link in Monday macro from

```
C:\Reports\Weekly Report\Week XX\Monday Report.xls
```

to

```
C:\Reports\Weekly Report\Week 42\Monday Report.xls
```

Is this possible to do?

I want to say thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Programmatic changing macros is dangerous. Check [VBE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443984(v=vs.60).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim weekNr as Integer
Dim fName as Variant

Sheets(YourSheet).Activate
weekNr = Sheets(CurrentSN).Range("A5").Select

fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="C:\Reports\Weekly Report\Week" & weekNr & "\Monday Report.xls", _
            filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls", _
            Title:="This example copies the ActiveSheet to a new workbook")

Set ActWb = ActiveWorkbook

ActWb .SaveAs fname, FileFormat:=-4143, CreateBackup:=False
ActWb .Close False
Set ActWb = Nothing
```

Use fileformat -4143 for 2000-2003 format.